# Multitouch tap count

Tags: c#, android, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Help me to change my "ClickCounter.cs" with OnMouseButton() for mobile phone with multitouch. I want to show how many time I tap on display, but my var "count" incremented every frame in Update().
My code for mouse -  "ClickCounter.cs"

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickCounter : MonoBehaviour
{

    Text ScoreText; //var for my text

    void Start()
    {
        ScoreText = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Text>();
    }


    int count = 0;
    void OnMouseDown() //func count my click, but cant counting multitouch 
    {
       count++;
       ScoreText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString(); //text field with score (click count)
       GameObject.Find("Pride").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Click"); //some animation
       Debug.Log(count);

    }
}
```

My code for android

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text scoreText;

    void Start()
    {
        scoreText = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Text>(); //same 
    }


    void Update ()
    {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0) Counter(); //touch check
    }

    int count = 0;
    void Counter() //
    {
            count++;
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
            GameObject.Find("Pride").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Click");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if (Input.touchCount > 0)` is always `true` when one finger or more is placed on the screen. Since this is ran in the Update function, `Counter()` will be called dozens of times per second depending on your frame-rate.

You also have to check for `TouchPhase.Ended` or `TouchPhase.Began`.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) Debug.Log("Tapped");
```

or

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) Debug.Log("Tapped");
```

should do it.

Even if this should work, there is another problem. It won't work with multiple fingers tapping at the-same time. You have to loop over `Input.touchCount` to make this work with multiple fingers.

Another thing is that a tap is supposed to have a timer. A timer that determines if this should be considered as a tap or not. For example, holding finger on the screen for more than a second should not be called a tap. The solution below solves all those problem. The `timeOut` variable can be used to set how long a player should holder their finger on the screen to be considered as a tap.

For default, anything more than `0.5` second is not a tap.

```
float[] fingerIdTimer = new float[5] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f }; //5 fingers max
bool[] fingerIdValid = new bool[5] { true, true, true, true, true }; //One determine invalid, must be rest in TouchPhase.Ended
const float timeOut = 0.5f; //Anything more than 0 and less than timeOut value is tap

void Update()
{
    //Loop over all finger touching the screen
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        //Will only increment if finger is valid
        if (fingerIdValid[i])
        {
            fingerIdTimer[i] += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //If we reach the time out value and finger is still valid reset the finger id
        if (fingerIdTimer[i] > timeOut && fingerIdValid[i])
        {
            fingerIdTimer[i] = 0f; //Reset Held Time
            fingerIdValid[i] = false; //Invalid
            OnTapFailed(i, fingerIdTimer[i]);
        }

        //After touch is released, Anything more than 0 and less than timerOut value is tap
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (fingerIdTimer[i] > 0 && fingerIdTimer[i] < timeOut)
            {
                OnTapSuccess(i, fingerIdTimer[i]);
            }

            fingerIdTimer[i] = 0f; //Reset Held Time when released
            fingerIdValid[i] = true; //Reset Invalid when released
        }
    }
}

int count = 0;

//Tap was successful
void OnTapSuccess(int fingerId, float heldTime)
{
    count++; //Increment the tap count

    Debug.Log("Tapped Count: " + count + "\r\n"
        + "Finger ID: " + fingerId + "\r\n"
        + "Held Time: " + heldTime);

    //scoreText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    //GameObject.Find("Pride").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Click");
}

//Tap failed (Time out Occured)
void OnTapFailed(int fingerId, float heldTime)
{
    Debug.Log("Tap Failed: " + fingerId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate! It's working perfectly! I was trying "TouchPhase.Ended & TouchPhase.Began", script was working, but  I lost multitouch  ability. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you set count = 0, but outside of the Update function. So after one touch, count will always be !0. Just put this satement in the function and it will work.

Comment: when I put this var inside function, I get "count = 1" on exit